# custom google map polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a functional custom Google Map running as the background of a page on a demo website I'm building. The code for the map as well as the div it's contained in is as follows:

```
    <div id="fullBG" style="')" ><script>
function initMap() {
  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.province",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },
{
      }

], {
      name: 'Custom Style'
  });
  var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('fullBG'), {
    zoom: 4, 
    center: {lat: 46.902983, lng: -41.742671},
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: []

    }
  });
 map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
}



    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[my API key]&signed_in=false&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script></div>
```

I'm trying to add a simple polyline as advised by the Developers pages on Google with the following code:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

I've tried pasting the polyline code in various places in the map code but I can't get it to work. I've also tried changing some of the variables but again to no avail.

This has led to frustration and the realisation that I need to learn more of the basics rather than attempting to hash together a solution, but in the meantime if anyone could advise on how to get this line added I'd be very grateful!

Comment: [I see the polyline if I add it in to your code (it goes from the west coast of the US to Australia)](http://jsfiddle.net/uwp965sp/)

Comment: It's definitely not working from this end. Never mind! Thanks for answering.

Comment: Do you see the polyline in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwp965sp/)?  If so, how is your code different from that in the fiddle.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I do indeed, thanks for the fiddle (I missed it first time round, been a long day..!). I've tinkered some more and realise where I went wrong with your help. Thanks very much (and sorry for the basic question!). Edit: thanks for the info on MCV examples too.

Answer (score 0):

I have played a little with you code ..

this seems to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Simple Polygon</title>
      <style>
        html, body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        #map, #fullBG {
          height: 100%;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="fullBG"  ></div>
  <script>

    function initMap() {
      var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
      },{
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
      },
    {
          }

    ], {
          name: 'Custom Style'
      });


      var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('fullBG'), {
        zoom: 4, 
        center: {lat: 46.902983, lng: -41.742671},
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: []

        }
      });
      map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
      map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);

      var flightPlanCoordinates = [
          {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
          {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
          {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
          {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
        ];

        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: flightPlanCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

        flightPath.setMap(map);

    }

  </script>
  <script async defer
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

i have found four error

- the google api keys not properly set
- the script inside the map div
- the style non settend correctly in you fullBG div
- and the size for the map div not setted

Comment: Thank you - I was trying to call the script via a custom field in Wordpress and ended up getting jumbled up horribly. With your help and the other comments I managed to sort it - thanks!